# WPF Viewbox and Image size

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create the window that would show list of pictures one below the other. I've created control that contains ViewBox and Image in it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="..."
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox Name="viewbox">
            <Image Height="10" Name="image" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

public BitmapImage Image
{
    get { return image.Source as BitmapImage; }
    set { changeImage(value); }
}
public SingleIllustrationViewer()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
private void changeImage(BitmapImage img)
{
    System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
    float dpiX = graphics.DpiX / 96;
    this.image.BeginInit();
    this.image.Source = img;
    this.image.EndInit();
    this.image.Width = img.PixelWidth / img.DpiX * dpiX;
}
```

and I'm placing Images on window like this:

```
double margin = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < illustrations.Count; i++)
{
    String path = illustrations[i].printVersions.Last<String>();
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));

    Controls.SingleIllustrationViewer iv = new Controls.SingleIllustrationViewer();
    iv.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
    iv.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    iv.Margin = new Thickness(50, margin, 0, 0);
    iv.Image = bmp;
    grid.Children.Add(iv);
    margin += iv.Image.Height + 20;
}
```

So, for example, I've placed 3 pictures (all 3 of same width) like this, and received such an interesting behavior: first one is good, second smaller, third smaller than a second. Here is the screen shot:
[image: scree shot]

Maybe someone can tell me why is that so, and how can fix this, to see all those picture in the same width?

Thanks!

Regards, Tomas

Comment: Did you try the Stretch property of the ViewBox : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You increased the margin for each Images: `margin += iv.Image.Height + 20;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause:

You did not specify the Height or Width of the UserControl, so when the first `SingleIllustrationViewer` is added to the `Grid`, it will be stretched to occupied all available space until it reaches the edge of the `Grid`. The same happens to the second one, but it is constrained to a smaller region due to the incremented `margin`.

The size specified as

```
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
```

is only used by designer, set the size like

```
Height="300" Width="300"
```

And then, put you viewers in a `StackPanel` instead of a `Grid`, then you don't have to calculate the Margin of a viewer base on the last viewer's position. `StackPanel` is a container that stacks its children in one direction, vertically or horizontally.

```
for (int i = 0; i < illustrations.Count; i++)
{
    String path = illustrations[i].printVersions.Last<String>();
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));

    Controls.SingleIllustrationViewer iv = new Controls.SingleIllustrationViewer();
    iv.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
    iv.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    iv.Margin = new Thickness(50, 0, 0, 20); //50 px to the left, 20 px to the next child 
    iv.Image = bmp;
    stackPanel1.Children.Add(iv);
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But if I don't increment margin pictures are placed one on another.

Comment: Put you viewers in a `StackPanel` instead of a `Grid`, then you don't have to calculate the Margin of a viewer base on the last viewer's position. StackPanel is a container that stacks its children in one direction, vertically or horizontally.

Comment: I've tried that, but now I see only my first image.

Comment: I've added `ScrollViewer` and see that somehow he moved second picture significantly downward. But I think my question is answered. Thanks!

Comment: _Could you join this chatting room?_ 
I can't, I don't have enough reputation.